# How to find out which collection view cell is tapped inside collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, collectionview

I am having a table view and inside it a collection view. I want to find out which collection view cell is tapped and also indexpath.row of corresponding table view cell.(Right now what i am able to get indexpath.row of collection view cell from didSelectRowAtIndexPath() but not able to find out there in which table view cell corresponding cell is present.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, let me know if it works for you:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect frame = [collectionView convertRect:cell.frame toView:tblView];
    NSIndexPath *tblIndexPath = [tblView indexPathForRowAtPoint:frame.origin];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, please mark it as answer if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Some corrections first.

Collection view delegate method is [didSelectItemAt](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) not 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath(). Also since you are using collection view get the item number by using `indexPath.item` not `indexPath.row`(you can use `row` but collection view has no rows  it has collection of items. So using `item` is intuitive)

Now for your query you can add `cell.tag = indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of **table view**

Now inside your collection view delegate method `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)
:` you can use `self.tag` to know which table view cell your collection view is in.

Comment: I am not getting self.tag inside collection view delegate method which u mentioned. Btw  my query is solved now, thanks for giving ur time.